Patent Claims Examined?
I am not sure I can ask so many question in same day or not, but I hope so.
this is my 1st time to apply for a patent, and I made a lot of mistakes in description, embodiments, and claims, based on some experts here, my application will be reviewed and examined by the examiner after the publication.
but I DID get two reports from UK examiner asking me to amended my claims but not accept me amending my description & embodiment, after two times amendment, I reduced my claims to 1 independent claim, and 2 dependent claims, ( very short sentence, less than 60 words in total), I didn't get her feedback anymore.
I appreciate her patience and understanding, and I know I might cost her extra time. I am sure she had a quick review and preliminary check on my application. could I say that I will have less problem in her late examination? and my application most likely to be approved?


Without any details no one can answer if things will go smoothly from here. If you did it yourself and you think you made many mistakes I’m not optimistic about the outcome.

Hi George, I DID it myself, could I say the worst scenario is I apply it again? or once they published it, no matter it is novel and new or not, if the patent office reject it finally, then no one can apply it again including myself? do you think this is an OFFICE ACTION, or just a brief report? then what is an OFFICE ACTION, she pointed out a lot of my problems.

You can’t apply again - if you can’t tell whether or not you received an office action it is unlikely you can respond effectively to one.
